# Move a documentation topic to another tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation

I'm trying to find a way to move a topic from one tag to another. What is the process for this? There are [Spring Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) topics within the Java tag, but there's now a Spring tag which they could be moved to.

I couldn't see anything in the UI to move topics, only a way to move examples between topics in the same tag.

Comment: I don't find a possibility either. We would need this for the iOS, macOS and cocoa tags, because I think we'll have to move topics very often between them: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328751/what-should-we-do-about-overlapping-topics/328770#328770

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving topics to another tag is now available!

The feature lives in the same spot as moving examples - the topic-level menu in Edit mode:

[image: "move" appears in the topic menu in edit mode]

Pick your destination tag by searching:

[image: "move topic" tab]

And the final confirmation step will notify you of any issues that prevent submission or allow you to make additional changes:

[image: confirmation step]

A few notes and caveats:

- a topic cannot be moved *and* deleted at the same time;
- introductory topics cannot be moved;
- other combinations of changes (e.g. example edits/moves + topic move) should be possible;
- versions will be reset to "all versions" on the topic, and inline versions in the Remarks section or in the examples will be stripped out<sup>*</sup> if they can't be matched to a version in the destination tag.

---

<sup>*</sup> As a v2 kind of thing, I'd like to implement something like being able to choose versions (both topic-level and inline) from the destination tag. I kind of want to observe what happens "in the wild" first, though.