# What should we do about overlapping topics?

Tags: support, documentation

There is currently an Array section in the iOS docs. Additionally, there is an Array section in both Objective-C and Swift. What are we supposed to do about this overlap?

Should the one in iOS be deleted?

Comment: Is there *any* difference between them at all?  I'm not one who is well-versed with iOS, Objective C or Swift.

Comment: iOS would be a superset of the two. Currently they do not all have the same information but technically should given that both Swift and Objective-C fall under iOS. Also I'm a fan of your name

Comment: The topic in iOS does only have 1 example in Swift and 1 pending in Objective-C. The topics in `Swift Language` and `Objective-C language` contain lots of information. Since arrays are features of the languages and NOT the OS, I would propose to keep the topics in `Swift Language` and `Objective-C` language.

Comment: It's I guess a bit problematic… MacOS and iOS APIs overlap; and Obj-C/Swift can use both (depending on where they're used)… for language parts the case is clear though as FelixSFD said

Comment: What about Berkeley Sockets, which are implemented in about every framework? Do we want to rewrite Beej's Guide to Network Programming once, or scatter it over the Sockets topic for every framework?

Comment: @CodeCaster well, we have the syscall about sockets… so languages directly exposing syscalls should have a common tag for these. specific languages with their own socket APIs shall obviously have their own article about it.

Comment: @bwoebi I'm not talking about the APIs, but the general principles that apply when using sockets (different kinds of sockets, how and why application protocols work, message framing, blocking/nonblocking, streaming, buffering, Nagle, ...).

Comment: @CodeCaster ah, you're meaning _network programming_ in general; sure _that_ should be its own tag, but this is quite language agnostic then again. It's about the protocols and what can be fine tuned…

Comment: @bwoebi sockets are the de facto implementation of network programming, but you're right, I've [committed to the proposal of that tag](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/network-programming/commit). But still, the same goes for for example arrays named here. They hardly ever differ between implementations, and I think we need a global "arrays" topic that explains the basics, so you can link to and include from that in language-specific topics.

Comment: So is the answer to this question that language specific things, such as Arrays, Strings, and Dictionaries should not be found in the `iOS` docs, but in `Swift` and `Objective-C`?

Comment: @CodeCaster oh, yeah, the core API of Berkeley sockets is pretty much everywhere. But everything else on top of it isn't (SO_REUSEPORT for example … and many other things you can tune here to make things efficient) Windows has a lot of APIs which are different here. [And also the different Unix flavors]

Comment: @WMios I think so. Also, you should probably have a `Cocoa` tag for everything what's shared on iOS and MacOS.

Comment: @bwoebi the tag `cocoa` was added 2 hours ago. So you think we should move all topics about APIs to `Cocoa` that work on iOS and macOS but are not a fundamental part of *Swift* and *Objective-C*?

Comment: Would new programmers know to even look for `Cocoa`?

Comment: @FelixSFD yes, that's what I'm suggesting. Prevents content duplication and actually is the name of this all.

Comment: @WMios it would not eliminate `iOS` since there are lot's of APIs exclusive for iOS (UIKit). But you are right. I don't think, new programmers would search there :-/ I'm not sure how we could solve it.

Comment: I modified my comment before since I realized it doesn't really eliminate iOS. I think it wouldn't hurt to have some overlap between Cocoa and iOS since new programmers probably wouldn't know what Cocoa is. That would sort of solve it, right?

Comment: @WMios it's not a perfect solution, but I think this works. If there are other tags with similar problems, it would be cool, linking topics to multiple tags. But it's not worth to introduce such a feature just for iOS and macOS ;-)

Comment: How do we handle frameworks such as Firebase or FacebookSDK? Would these also have their own documentation page?

Comment: @WMios in iOS docs you can easily have some references to the Cocoa doc… but the text should only be written once…

Comment: @Caleb for the FacebookSDK, I would propose to use the `facebook`-tag or maybe create `facebook-sdk` since it is available in many languages

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the case of arrays, I think it's pretty clear:

`Array` is a Swift-type and documented in the [Swift-Documentation](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/). It has nothing to do with iOS or macOS (except that both OS use Swift ;-) ). You can use this type in Swift-programs on other platforms than iOS and macOS because it's not a part of the iOS/macOS-SDK.

That's why I would put `Array` into *Swift Language*.

`NSArray` is a part of [*Foundation*](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/), which implements the fundamentals of Objective-C. Although it only runs on iOS and macOS, I would put this into *Objective-C Language*, since it belongs to the basics of Objective-C.

Comment: I think this makes sense. Strings aren't even documented in the `iOS` docs, no reason why Arrays should be.

Comment: The general principle behind: Always put topics in the most general tag, then link from the more specialized tags.