# How should we handle duplicate documentation examples?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I submitted some changes for a documentation example ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/reactjs/1419/using-reactjs-with-typescript#t=201607230130583017357)). But then noticed that the exact same example was posted in another location with the old code ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/typescript/1835/using-typescript-with-react-js-native#t=201607230125564875242)). How should we handle maintaining the duplicate examples? Should one be deleted? Or is there a way we can link the two together?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328751/what-should-we-do-about-overlapping-topics

Answer (score -1):

I would merge them into one. Take the best from the old code and the new code and make it one big doc.