# How is this off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

My question is: [Create storage profile for launching Azure VM via Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43424579/520567)

I see two votes for closing as off-topic. I believe my question is to the point, and I don't see any value adding additional information to it. I also fortunately received a good answer.

But I wonder, did I do something wrong, were the users voting for off-topic bots or something? How can I improve my questions in the future.

I'm sincerely wondering because I see many stupid questions with clueless code often asked without research done, that get upvoted. I always do research before asking (and asking rarely), but I generally feel my questions are unwelcome.

Comment: It seems like "can someone give me an example of..." questions tend to be marked that way. It would actually be interesting to ask more generally whether that type of question *should* be closed (i.e. if requesting examples *actually* constitutes a request for off-site resources).

Comment: Aww question is now closed. "_I see many stupid questions with clueless code often asked without research done, that get upvoted_" so true.

Comment: Why was this reopened? It's a poor question, it's unclear and easily resolved by looking at the documentation in the first place *(see the provided answer)*.

Comment: @denny it maybe true that doesn't mean it's a benchmark to measure other questions by. Unfortunately some just don't understand the [so] ethos and up-vote low quality, give me the code now questions. Doesn't make it right.

Comment: @Lankymart, if you payed attention to check the answer you would have seen in fact these examples are in a different repo and not referred to fron the documentation.

Comment: It doesn't matter where it came from, it's the top result on Google. I find it without the answer in less than 5 minutes using [`create_storage_profile ruby`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=off&ei=kWP4WKeqLMbfwAL04rJQ&q=create_storage_profile+ruby&oq=create_storage_profile+ruby&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...15658.17037.0.17704.6.6.0.0.0.0.139.568.2j3.5.0....0...1c..64.mobile-gws-serp..1.4.485...0i13k1j0i30k1j0i8i30k1j0i8i10i30k1j33i22i29i30k1j33i160k1.1aL7K-GngAQ). Again, what research did you do?

Comment: @Lankymart, I have read the SDK documentation (top level, compute and storage), read through spec in compute and storage parts of the SDK, also searched using some terms (not exactly your suggested terms above). I don't think I tried `create_storage_profile` because it is not part of official API but used similar terms. Btw your search doesn't work for me, not sure what you have found. For me top answers are SDK docs and my stackoverflow question. I don't see the examples repo that actually contains the answer.

Comment: @Lankymart RTFM is not a close reason. If a question shows a lack of research effort, close it as a duplicate. If there are no duplicates, it cannot possibly show a lack of research effort because only research on Stack Overflow counts as research at all.

Comment: Old people like to thought police; when too many old mods are online at the time your question comes up, you will face the juvenoia attack.

Comment: @Lankymart Answers being easily searchable on Google and answers can be gleaned from documentation is not and has never been a close reason for SO. The whole reason for the existence of SO is to be a high quality repository of answers to tech questions. If an answer is on Google but it's not on SO then write it as an answer so that the SO answer ranks higher than what was originally on Google

Comment: @slebetman the issue is lack of research effort with one keyword I was able to find the answer in less than five minutes on Google *(I don't even code Ruby)*. It screams of "give me the codex" questions. It's basic programming skill, knowing how to research a topic. The only time I ever ask a question on [so] is when I've exhausted all possibilities, then if I found an answer I might come back to add one for the benefit of others. It lacks research effort, it's unclear and I seen questions closed for less.

Comment: @slebetman What's worse I posted an answer *(against my better judgement)* only to [be told](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424579/create-storage-profile-for-launching-azure-vm-via-ruby/43513536?noredirect=1#comment74081375_43513536) its incomplete, which I did purposefully. I provided the definition they where looking for, any extra references *(which is always going to be the case)* would be up to them to dig into.

Comment: @TinyGiant RTFM can be a close reason, if the question is asking for utterly basic stuff. This is still a site for professional/enthusiast _programmers_, meaning people who have at least a bit of a clue about the topic discussed. Questions that can be answered by a quick RTFM or a glance in a beginner-level programming book are almost certainly of poor quality. As for the specific case, I have no technical knowledge about it and can't tell if it is good or bad (or if it is too broad).

Comment: @lundin oh sorry, i must have missed the announcement for the rtfm close reason. I cant seem to find it in the close dialog. Mind posting a screenshot so i can find it?

Comment: @TinyGiant There is no community consensus. There used to be an option "user must demonstrate minimum knowledge of the topic" but it was removed by SO employees, not by community consensus. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253473/should-we-add-rtfm-to-the-list-of-off-topic-close-reasons

Comment: It was removed because it makes no sense as a close reason, and it was being abused far more than it was being used correctly. @lundin

Comment: @TinyGiant No that's nonsense. It was what SO staff said, but there was no evidence about this, nor any community consensus to remove the close reason. Since then, the quality of SO has dropped significantly and this is one of the reasons. And this happened before you even joined SO, so there is no need to pretend that you were there to witness the effect before and after this change...

Comment: @Lundin I may have joined the site after the close reason was removed, but I've done a lot of research on meta in my time here, and have seen many questions closed for that reason nonsensically. It was used as a super downvote, how users are no using the typo close reason.

Comment: @Lundin One of the greatest uses of SO is to be able to look up common questions and quickly find vetted answers. What's the point/benefit of not allowing a question for no other reason than it's simple/could have been easily looked up? Simple questions often have the highest benefit to future users. I can't actually think of a single reason why this in itself is a bad thing.

Comment: @aw04 The point is that SO is not replacement for ways of traditional study, such as reading books, tutorials or attending classes. The intent of SO was never to become an interactive beginner tutorial or even to teach programming. The intent was to provide Q&A for enthusiast and professional _programmers_ - a programmer being someone with at least half-decent knowledge of at least one programming language.

Comment: For the sake of traffic = cash, the site has been hijacked for the beginner tutorial purpose, not so much a choice by the community as by the owners of the site, who have removed moderator tools that would allow us to block utterly basic questions (first chapters of any programming book questions). As a result, the quality of the site has rapidly dropped over the last years and experts become inactive, since many of them don't want to drown in a flood of newbie questions.

Comment: @Lundin Sure, I agree with all of your points and you're spot on with traffic=cash but IMO the bigger issues are the debugging questions/super specific problems/syntax errors/etc that are helpful to no one but the OP (of which there are many...) as opposed to questions that have no other fault than being basic.

Comment: @aw04 Such questions are already explicitly off-topic though. There's the "debugging help with no MCVE" close reason and there's the "simple typo" close reason. This is because they are just as useless to every _programmer_ on this site as questions of the nature "how do I print hello world".

Comment: Suppose we had a professional scuba diving site. Then people keep visiting the site and asking "how do I swim?"  "how do I hold my breath?"  "can I breathe under water?" and other crap that is completely useless to the site. They should have taken a basic swimming class or asked their parents. The only purpose such questions could fill would be to smack the next person asking the very same thing in the head with a pre-written answer. But how this pre-written smacking tool makes the question "how do I swim" on-topic on a professional scuba diving site, I have no idea.

Comment: @Lundin Fair enough, but I guess I look at it the opposite way as, why not? People will not stop asking basic questions without raising the bar to ask questions (which is a separate discussion entirely). So you can either continuously close and make questions disappear or you can keep around a single dupe target. Either way you need to address each one, but the latter option brings substantial benefit (views) to SO.

Comment: @aw04 The key might be to give "gold badge" holders full close rights like they currently have for duplicates. The only benefit of having a duplicate like the one you describe is that crap questions can be instantly "dupe hammered". Personally I couldn't care less about how many views SO are getting.

Comment: @Lundin Agreed, yes, better/easier way of dealing with duplicates is key.

Answer (score 24):

> [W]ere the users voting for off-topic bots or something?

To the best of my knowledge, this is not a thing that happens.

> I believe my question is to the point, and I don't see any value adding additional information to it.

Your question was closed for the wrong reason.  The correct closure reason is that **you were asking for help with code which is not in the question itself** (specifically, "the example in the compute API").  You pasted one part of the example, but the situation as a whole is unclear because we have to consult an off-site resource to understand what you are asking.  Off-site resources could change.  Your question should *always* include the exact code you are having trouble with.

> I always do research before asking (and asking rarely)

This is not evident from your question.  Unfortunately, it's difficult to get that right.  People tend to be more forgiving on this point if your question looks like this:

> I'm trying to [do something].
>
> [code]
>
> I'm having problem A [an error message, "it does X but I want it to do Y," etc.].  I looked at the [documentation](http://example.com/docs.html), but it only seems to talk about problems B, C, and D, and my problem isn't mentioned there.  My code looks pretty similar to their sample code, so I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

In this *particular* case, that kind of formula is difficult to use, however.  Combined with the off-site code, it's an obvious downvote-and-close.

Comment: It's unclear and should be closed.

Comment: what code would you add in this case? it seems the whole problem is he can't find the code he needs in the documentation/example... sure you could add everything else for context, but it's unclear to me how that's helpful?

Comment: @aw04: There is code on the page which OP linked to.  That code is relevant to the question.

Comment: not sure i agree, i know nothing about the topic and i was able to find all i need to answer the question with the code snippet provided (i didn't click any of the external links...)

Comment: @aw04 simple wouldn't ask the question in the first place.